# Conda will not let me activate environments

Tags: python, python-3.x, conda, miniconda

I downloaded and installed miniconda.

First of all, the name of the executable is not `conda`, but `_conda`.

Anyway, i type:

```
_conda create -n test python=3.8.3
```

I proceed and it installs the packages.

I then try to activate the environment with `_conda activate test`

I get this:

```
CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda
activate'.
If using 'conda activate' from a batch script, change your
invocation to 'CALL conda.bat activate'.

To initialize your shell, run

    $ conda init <SHELL_NAME>

Currently supported shells are:
  - bash
  - cmd.exe
  - fish
  - tcsh
  - xonsh
  - zsh
  - powershell

See 'conda init --help' for more information and options.

IMPORTANT: You may need to close and restart your shell after running 'conda init'.
```

So i type `_conda init cmd.exe`

And this is what i get:

```
WARNING: Cannot install xonsh wrapper without a python interpreter in prefix: C:
\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI50762
needs sudo    C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI50762\Scripts\conda.exe
needs sudo    C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI50762\Scripts\conda-env.exe
modified      C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI50762\Scripts\conda-script.py
modified      C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI50762\Scripts\conda-env-script.py
needs sudo    C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI50762\condabin\conda.bat
needs sudo    C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI50762\Library\bin\conda.bat
needs sudo    C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI50762\condabin\_conda_activate.bat
needs sudo    C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI50762\condabin\rename_tmp.bat
needs sudo    C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI50762\condabin\conda_auto_activate.bat
needs sudo    C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI50762\condabin\conda_hook.bat
needs sudo    C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI50762\Scripts\activate.bat
needs sudo    C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI50762\condabin\activate.bat
needs sudo    C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI50762\condabin\deactivate.bat
needs sudo    C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI50762\Scripts\activate
needs sudo    C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI50762\Scripts\deactivate
needs sudo    C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI50762\etc\profile.d\conda.sh

needs sudo    C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI50762\etc\fish\conf.d\conda.fish
needs sudo    C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI50762\shell\condabin\Conda.psm1
needs sudo    C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI50762\shell\condabin\conda-hook.ps1
needs sudo    C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI50762\etc\profile.d\conda.csh
modified      HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun

==> For changes to take effect, close and re-open your current shell. <==

Operation failed.
```

I also tried `_conda init powershell` and `_conda init bash`, and they both failed.

Comment: seems like you installed conda or all users or as a admin. open up your terminal as a admin and try again

Comment: @PaulH I just did and same results.

Comment: recommend starting over from scratch

Comment: @PaulH Did it all from the beginning in an administrator shell. Exactly the same results.

Comment: if you start over, don't install as an admin and don't install for all users

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had this same issue. Use the `conda.bat` file inside of `<anaconda_install_dir>\condabin` instead of the root `_conda.exe`.

You should then be able to run `conda activate test` (if you add `<anaconda_install_dir>\condabin` to `PATH`).