# Conda init not activating environments, Windows 10

Tags: conda, anaconda3

I am having the same issue as [this person](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63508641/conda-will-not-let-me-activate-environments), down to the letter, where trying to run `conda activate myenv` returns:

```
C:\Users\nt1\AppData\Local\anaconda3>_conda init cmd.exe
WARNING: Cannot install xonsh wrapper without a python interpreter in prefix: C:\Users\nt1\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI36162
ERROR during elevated execution.
  rc: [WinError 0] The operation completed successfully.
needs sudo    C:\Users\nt1\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI36162\Scripts\conda.exe
needs sudo    C:\Users\nt1\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI36162\Scripts\conda-env.exe
modified      C:\Users\nt1\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI36162\Scripts\conda-script.py
modified      C:\Users\nt1\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI36162\Scripts\conda-env-script.py
needs sudo    C:\Users\nt1\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI36162\condabin\conda.bat
needs sudo    C:\Users\nt1\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI36162\Library\bin\conda.bat
needs sudo    C:\Users\nt1\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI36162\condabin\_conda_activate.bat
needs sudo    C:\Users\nt1\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI36162\condabin\rename_tmp.bat
needs sudo    C:\Users\nt1\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI36162\condabin\conda_auto_activate.bat
needs sudo    C:\Users\nt1\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI36162\condabin\conda_hook.bat
needs sudo    C:\Users\nt1\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI36162\Scripts\activate.bat
needs sudo    C:\Users\nt1\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI36162\condabin\activate.bat
needs sudo    C:\Users\nt1\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI36162\condabin\deactivate.bat
needs sudo    C:\Users\nt1\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI36162\Scripts\activate
needs sudo    C:\Users\nt1\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI36162\Scripts\deactivate
needs sudo    C:\Users\nt1\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI36162\etc\profile.d\conda.sh
needs sudo    C:\Users\nt1\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI36162\etc\fish\conf.d\conda.fish
needs sudo    C:\Users\nt1\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI36162\shell\condabin\Conda.psm1
needs sudo    C:\Users\nt1\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI36162\shell\condabin\conda-hook.ps1
needs sudo    C:\Users\nt1\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI36162\etc\profile.d\conda.csh
modified      HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun

==> For changes to take effect, close and re-open your current shell. <==

Operation failed.

C:\Users\nt1\AppData\Local\anaconda3>
```

Also, the executable is _conda rather than conda. That _MEI36162 directory doesn't actually seem to exist, or it's not a directory that I can see in the Windows file explorer (even with the show hidden items box checked) or cd into from the command prompt. I guess maybe it's supposed to be created when you run the command and deleted immediately, but I don't know.

The question I linked to was asked over three years ago and none of the answers were helpful to me. Somebody suggested using `conda.bat` in `condabin` instead of the `_conda.exe` file but that returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\nt1\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py", line 11, in <module>
    from conda.cli import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'conda'
```

I'll add that somebody in response to a similar question suggested running the commands in anaconda prompt; opening anaconda prompt presents me immediately with the same error.

Also, for clarity: I have anaconda3, anaconda3/Scripts, and anaconda3/condabin all added to Path.

Thanks in advance.